# Expo build ignores the Android Manifest

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to build my react native app with `expo build:android -t apk`. It produces a functional apk; however, the apk requires some default permissions, although I removed them. It also ignores the app icon. I set it in both app.json and Manifest.

I have a feeling that I am missing something before `expo build:android -t apk` command. The reason that I don't use `react-native run-android`, it produces a broken apk that can be installed on the phone but does not run.

Please find my manifest and app.json below.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.hergun1isfikri"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <!-- OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS, REMOVE WHATEVER YOU DO NOT NEED -->
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"  />


    <!-- These require runtime permissions on M -->
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"  />
    <uses-permission tools:node="remove" android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"  />
    <!-- END OPTIONAL PERMISSIONS -->

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

app.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "displayName": "myapp",
  "icon": "./assets/ic_launcher.png",
  "expo": {
    "name": "myapp",
    "slug": "myapp",
    "privacy": "unlisted",
    "sdkVersion": "36.0.0",
    "version": "3.0.0",
    "entryPoint": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ],
    "android": {
      "package": "com.myapp.myapp",

      "versionCode": 3,

      "config": {

        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "xxx"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expo should ignore all native files and folders. All the changes you need to make can be made through the `app.json` file. That's one of the big points about expo. Also, it gives you the option of building all the keys and permissions needed for the app during the build process

Comment: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/permissions/#android